# «В связи с этим». Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли в следующем предложении запятая?

**В связи с этим(,) я могу сделать выводы.**

Answer (score 1):

**В связи с этим я могу сделать выводы.**
*В связи с этим я хотел задать вам два вопроса.

В связи с этим я уже полгода не могу получить пенсию.*

В этих простых предложениях словосочетание **в связи с этим** (предлог + местоимение) от последующего текста запятой не отделяется. Словосочетание не требует обособления, так как не несет никаких выделительных функций и не является вводным.

**В связи с** — это производный предлог, образованный от существительного (его можно заменить на **по причине**).
Предлог может употребляться как с существительным, так и с местоимением:
в связи с похолоданием; в связи с подорожанием; в связи с его решением; в связи с этим мероприятием...

[«В связи с этим» в начале предложения](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/nachale-v-svyazi-s-etim-zapyataya.html)
[В связи с этим — нужна ли запятая?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1737297-v-svjazi-s-etim-nuzhna-li-zapjataja.html)

Answer (score 1):

***В связи с этим я могу сделать выводы.***

Устойчивый нераспространенный обстоятельственный оборот ***в связи с этим*** обычно не обособляется, в том числе в этом предложении.

**Примечание**

**Но нельзя сказать, что он не обособляется никогда** (по принципу *никогда не говори никогда*).

К примеру, одиночное обстоятельство тоже, как правило, не обособляется, но в определенных случаях автор может его обособить,  придав ему значение добавочного сообщения или смыслового выделения, например: Они, с выставки, уехали в Крым (М. Г.)  В аудиторию, один за другим, входили студенты для сдачи экзамена; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Примеры с обособлением:

...это вопрос к тому, насколько мы сами понимаем риски этой среды обитания для наших мозгов, и что мы делаем, **в связи с этим**, чтобы сохранить собственную способность к мышлению в этой среде... [ Информационная псевдодебильность (2015)]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой сейчас самый точный и самый обширный словарь переносов? И, **в связи с этим**, подскажите, правильно ли расставлены переносы: россий-ский, пун-кта...

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна.

Правило:

**Запятая ставится только в том случае, если оборот, начинающийся предлогом "в связи с", носит характер присоединительного (если перед этими словами есть интонационная пауза). Если паузы перед этими словами нет, запятая не нужна.**

Оборот очень **короткий** и нет никакой интонационной паузы. Поэтому запятая не ставится. Пауза (и запятая) обычно тогда, когда оборот большой.

Comment: Предлог **в связи с** стоит в начале предложения — здесь нет никакого присоединительного характера и интонационной паузы (и быть не может). Если Вы цитируете **«правило»** с _Грамоты_, то дайте весь контекст. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E Производственная необходимость в нашем предложении никак не подходит.